# What is the django-method of fetching the instance in a OneToOneField, accesed from a ManyToManyRelatedManager?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was wondering what is the most django correct way of fetching the instance in an `OneToOneField`, when the instance I'm fetching from is accessed through a `ManyToManyRelatedManager`?

Specifically, I have a `CustomGroup` model that has a `OneToOneField` to `auth.Group`. Then I want to fetch each `CustomGroup` instance from the user instance, through the `groups` manager.

These are my models:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, Group
from django.db import models

class CustomGroup(models.Model):
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="custom_group")


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # my custom fields
```

I would like to have a `get_custom_groups` method on the `CustomUser` model that returns a `RelatedManager` with the base queryset as all the `CustomGroup` that this user is related to (much like `user.groups`, but only with `CustomGroup` as the model).

What I have usually done is something like this:

```py
def get_custom_groups(self):
    custom_group_ids = self.groups.all().values_list("custom_group", flat=True)
    return CustromGroup.objects.filter(id__in=custom_group_ids)
```

Is this the best way of doing this, or is there another, smarter way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the best way of doing this, or is there another, smarter way?

**No**, there is no need to first fetch the `custom_group` items, etc. We can filter directly with:

```
def get_custom_groups(self):
    return CustromGroup.objects.filter(group__user=self)
```